# Updating MySQL database values using DataGridView on Visual C++ Windows Form

Tags: c++, mysql, winforms, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

I have searched everywhere, but  i haven't found a working method or code to update my database ( using MySQL ) on a VC++ Windows form. Tutorials and answers are there regarding the C# code in abundance. I am using the following code to load database values into the DatagridView.

```
        String^ constring1 =     L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        MySqlConnection^ conDataBase1 = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring1);
        MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase1 = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `database`.`reading`; ", conDataBase1);
        MySqlDataReader^ myReader1;

        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter^ sda = gcnew MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda->SelectCommand = cmdDataBase1;
            DataTable^ dbadataset = gcnew DataTable();
            sda->Fill(dbadataset);
            BindingSource^ bSource = gcnew BindingSource();

            bSource->DataSource = dbadataset;
            dataGridView1->DataSource = bSource;
            sda->Update(dbadataset);
        }

        catch (Exception^ ex)
        {
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
        }
```

It'd be great if anyone could help me out with the method or code to update the MySQL database using the DataGridView.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's with all the ^s and gcnews? What language is this?

Comment: This is Visual C++. I am working on a windows CLR form. ^s are used while declaring objects of classes and gcnew is used for memory allocation. This is the first time I'm working with Visual C++, I saw these on an online video tutorial. Sorry i I'm wrong about the above information. The tutorial didnt quite clarify the use of ^ or gcnew, but thats my inference.